# error converting string to int in javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm trying to convert a numeric string to a number, then I want to increase (or decrease) its value, and finally it should be written back to its original place (in a span). But I'm always getting NaN when I try parseInt:

```
        var like_value = "0";
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)//firefox
        like_value = document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML;
    else
        like_value = document.getElementById('mySpan').innerText;

    like_value = like_value.substring(1, like_value.length - 1);
    var real_number = parseInt(like_value, 10);
    real_number++;
    alert(real_number);//it displays NaN !!!
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)//firefox
        document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = real_number;
    else
        like_value = document.getElementById('mySpan').innerText = real_number;
```

I think there should be a problem in my substring, of course I get what I expect but perhaps it cannot be correctly converted to int

Comment: Did you try to debug to see how is your like_value ? Just add `console.log(like_value);` and type F12 to see the console.

Comment: I write it using alert, it is fine in like_value = like_value.substring(1, like_value.length - 1);
, but after parseInt I get NaN

Comment: This isn't relevant to your problem, but it is useful advise; browser sniffing is *sooo* 1500's. You should look at using ***feature detection*** instead (e.g. `"textContent" in document.createElement("div")` rather than `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1`

Comment: Why are you doing this substring operation Are you sure you have at least 3 chars in your number ?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: So what is the exact value being `alert`'d?

Comment: it displays NaN after parseInt, originally I have (11), I use substring to remove ( and ), then I try to covert "11" to 11, is it right?

Comment: You should trim it first, because if you have spaces around, the parentheses wouldn't be removed by the substring operation : like_value=like_value.trim();

Comment: Please post html, mostly the part with mySpan I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `" (11)"` before the substring operation, you have `"(11"` after as it removes the first and last letter.

This parses as NaN.

The problem is that there are meany possible reasons to have spaces or new lines around your string.

I'd recommend to clean your string like this :

```
var like_value = document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML;
like_value = like_value.replace(/[\n\r\t\(\)]/g,); // this also remove the parenthesis
var real_number = parseInt(like_value, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying printing out what your like_value is. NaN is returned if the string can not be converted to a number, so something has to be wrong with your string